# Setting up Git Redmine hosting plugin

Tags: git, redmine

I'm trying to configure the Redmine Git hosting plugin but I'm struggling with some difficulties in setting up the proper permissions to the web and git users. When I access the plugin settings interface, the setting Git user is able to sudo to Web user? is marked as invalid.

The error message which is being logged on the server, is the following one:

> Testing if git user("git") can sudo to web user("root")
>   Error while testing sudo_git_to_web_user:

As far I understand, the user running the web server is root and that doesn't seem well. How can I actually verify the user who is running the web server? I need to change it to www-data, since its expected user by gitolite.

Comment: Belongs on [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com) -- Moderators please and thank ya kindly. Regarding question: Never run a web server as root; that's very insecure! :) If you're running Apache you can edit the user in the Apache config file, whose location will depend on the distro/operating system you're running. For example, on Ubuntu, it's in /etc/apache2/envvars and you have to set `export APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data; export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=www-data`

Comment: @allquixotic: If you think a question belongs on another site, please just flag it. By mentioning the other site in the comments, users often post on multiple sites, which is discouraged. By flagging the question, the question will be migrated to another site if your flag was valid. Thanks

Comment: This question is valid on Super User.